# NoClassDefFoundError Error invoking a method

Tags: java

I am getting this error while i have added the dependecies required commons-codec.

```
Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getPassword' in  class com.soft.DbGenUtl threw exception class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:246)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:175)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:220)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:55)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIfStatement.render(ASTIfStatement.java:70)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:230)
        at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:256)
        at com.cwsoft.tools.filegenerator.VelocityTemplateProcessor.process(VelocityTemplateProcessor.java:63)
        at com.cwsoft.tools.filegenerator.FileGenerator.execute(FileGenerator.java:121)
        at com.cwsoft.tools.filegenerator.ant.FileGenerateTask.execute(FileGenerateTask.java:41)
        ... 46 more
```

```
maven2/repository/local/org/apache/commons/codec/binary] ls -lrt
total 144
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup       3119 Dec 20 2013  StringUtils.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup       4356 Dec 20 2013  Hex.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup       3252 Dec 20 2013  BinaryCodec.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup       2372 Dec 20 2013  BaseNCodecOutputStream.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup       3127 Dec 20 2013  BaseNCodecInputStream.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup       5348 Dec 20 2013  BaseNCodec.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup       1409 Dec 20 2013  BaseNCodec$Context.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup        939 Dec 20 2013  Base64OutputStream.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup        929 Dec 20 2013  Base64InputStream.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup       9201 Dec 20 2013  Base64.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup        939 Dec 20 2013  Base32OutputStream.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup        929 Dec 20 2013  Base32InputStream.class
-rw-r-----    1 ppk      ppkgroup       7605 Dec 20 2013  Base32.class
```

Could you please suggest what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Just because these classes exist in some maven2 repo does not mean that your application can find them there. How do you package/run your application and why do you assume this should be working?

Comment: These jobs are configured through Jenkins and currently jframe is failing in a project.
/projects/jframe/cwsoft-jframe-listsmanagement-service/target/antrun/build-main.xml:16: The following error occurred while executing this line:
projects/jframe/cwsoft-jframe-listsmanagement-service/buildForMaven2.xml:19: org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getPassword' in  class com.cwsoft.uml.meta.wrapper.DbGenUtl threw exception class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64